# template typedef with std::vector to have custom allocator

Tags: c++, templates, g++, typedef, c++03

I would like to define a custom vector class that uses std::vector class with custom allocator as below:

```
template <class T>
typedef std::vector<T, MyLib::MyAlloc<T> > my_vector;
```

Then, when I ttry to use it as:

```
  my_vector<std::string> v;
```

My g++ 2.95.3 Compiler  on Solaris 10 complains stating that

```
 template declaration of `typedef class vector<T,MyLib::MyAlloc<T1> > my_vector'
aggregate `class my_vector<basic_string<char,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> > > v' has incomplete type and cannot be initialized
```

Please help me to correct the snippet.

Comment: your error says `....MyLib::MyAlloc<T1>`  but there is no `T1` in the code. If this is really the code and the error message then this is quite strange

Comment: @tobi303 I am confused too

Answer (score 2):

C++11 supports this with the "new" type alias syntax:

```
template <class T>
using my_vector = std::vector<T, MyLib::MyAlloc<T> >;
```

The "old" form (`typedef`) cannot be used to create an alias template.

---

If C++11 or beyond is not an option. The only recourse is a template meta-function:

```
template <class T>
struct my_vector {
  typedef std::vector<T, MyLib::MyAlloc<T> > type;
};
```

Which can be used like this:

```
my_vector<std::string>::type v;
```

Or, since `std::vector` is a class type:

```
template <class T>
struct my_vector : std::vector<T, MyLib::MyAlloc<T> > {};
```

Which may be used as you originally wished it to be used.

Comment: Oops, but my compiler in this case is prior C++11, it's g++ 2.95.3

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana - Then the alias can't be used directly. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, this is ok for 2.95.3, but for member functions like push_back etc needs to be overridden for my_vector?

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana - No. It's public inheritance.